# python regex pattern not working properly

Tags: python, regex

Good day stackoverflow, I have a problem with my program. I want to test if the string I entered is alphanumeric or not.

```
def logUtb(fl, str):
now = datetime.datetime.now()
  fl.write(now.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M') + " - " + str + "\n");
  return;

#Test alphanumeric
def testValidationAlphaNum():
    valid = re.match('[A-Za-z0-9]', '!@#@$@$@')
    if valid == True:
        logUtb(f, 'Alphanumeric')
    else:
        logUtb(f, 'Unknown characters')
```

As you can see I entered '!@#@$@$@' to be tested by my regex pattern. Instead of return "Unknown characters" to  my report log it returns alphanumeric. Can you guys please tell me what seems to be wrong with my program? Thanks!

Comment: It's worth noting that there's a `str.isalnum()` function.

Comment: Your code returns `Unknown characters` for me. What is `f`? What is `logUtb`?

Comment: ``re.match`` with your parameters returns ``None`` to me, as it should (so it shouldn't be ``== True``). Also, your condition is incorrect: in case you did provide an alphanumeric string to ``match``, it would return a match object, which is not equal to ``True`` anyway.

Comment: I updated my code to explain what the function logUtb function is for

Comment: is there a str function for numeric and alphabets only kind sirs? sorry for the noob question. im still new to python by the way.

Comment: @cor03rock `str.isalnum()`

Comment: Okay. what my plan is to identify the input alphanum,numeric and alphabet input. I have coded to identify numeric and alphabet inputs but I want to change by using regex to shorten my code but I guess there is no other way then to use the old code i made with numeric and alphabet identifiers.

Comment: As written, the `re.match(...)` only checks the **first** character of the string.  If you want to use a regexp, change it to `[A-Za-z0-9]+$` to check the entire string.

Comment: @TimPeters thank you this worked out for me. the str.isalnum() is not working out for me. still returns the same problem Haidro  . I wonder for the downvotes. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with the others who have said that calling str.isalnum() would be a simpler option here.

However, I would like to point out a few things with regard to the regex pattern you tried. Like Alex Baldwin said, your pattern as-is will only be looking for a single alphanumeric at the beginning of the string. So, you could potentially have anything else in the rest of the string and still get a match.

What you should do instead is quantify your character class, and anchor that class to the end of the string. To test that the string contains some alphanumerics, you ought to choose the + quantifier, which looks for *at least one* alphanumeric. Make sure you use the $ to anchor the pattern to the end of the string, or else you could have some non-alphanumerics sneak in at the end:

```
re.match('[A-Za-z0-9]+$', '!@#@$@$@')
```

This will return false, of course, for the given string. The problem with using the * here is that it will return a MatchObject even against an empty string, and I assume you want there to be at least one alphanumeric character present. Notice also that using the ^ to anchor the character class to the beginning of the string is not necessary, because re.match() begins its search only at the beginning of the string. What you then want to test with your conditional is whether or not a MatchObject was returned by re.match():

```
valid = re.match('[A-Za-z0-9]+$', '!@#@$@$@')
    if valid:
        logUtb(f, 'Alphanumeric')
    else:
        logUtb(f, 'Unknown characters')
```

Additional information on the quantifiers and anchors can be found in the documentation:

http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html

Answer (score 4):

[`re.match()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) returns `None` if the string didn't match and a `MatchObject` if it did. So the `== True` test will never be satisfied. If you're really seeing the `'Alphanumeric'` output, then it's not a result of the code you have posted.

In any case, you should use [`str.isalnum()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.isalnum) for this:

```
>>> 'abc'.isalnum()
True
```

Comment: The questioner said that it is logging "Alphanumeric", which suggests the `== True` is being satisfied.

Comment: @Tim Is correct. If you run his code, it will return "Unknown characters"

Comment: so correct me if I am wrong. I can directly use if 'abc'.isalnum()   ?

Comment: @Tim Then there is something we are not seeing, because that test will never be satisfied in the code of the question. A `MatchObject` will never `== True`.

Comment: is there a str function for numeric and alphabets only kind sirs? sorry for the noob question. im still new to python by the way.

Comment: @cor03rock No, there isn't anything standard along those lines to my knowledge.

Comment: `if MatchObject` will return true if the matchobject exists, and false if it is a none.

Comment: @AlexBaldwin That's correct, because `MatchObject`s all have a boolean value of `True`. However comparing them via `== True` is a different story.

Comment: Okay. what my plan is to identify the input alphanum,numeric and alphabet input. I have coded to identify numeric and alphabet inputs but I want to change by using regex to shorten my code but I guess there is no other way then to use the old code i made with numeric and alphabet identifiers.

Comment: @arshajii, Ah! I see the difference. He should say `if valid` anyways because `if valid` and `if valid == True` are functionally identical and the "pythonic" way of doing it is `if valid` yes?

Comment: @cor03rock Please review the second link in my answer. There are also `str.isalpha()` and `str.isdigit()` methods.

Comment: @AlexBaldwin No, they are not functionally identical (try `if 2` and `if 2 == True`). The "right" way to do this would have been what you suggested, `if valid`. My point is that `valid == True` will never be satisfied here, as I explained in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
valid = re.match('[A-Za-z0-9]', '!@#@$@$@')
```

could be

```
valid = re.match(r'^\w*$', '!@#@$@$@')
```

and work. `\w` is alpha numeric. (I'd like to add that underscores are alphanumeric, according to python.) So if you don't want those, your regex should be: `^[A-Za-z0-9]*$`

OR, it could `[^_/W]`

but `if valid == True` must be `if valid` to work.

Comment: `\w` also includes underscores.

Comment: Which are alphanumeric! If he doesn't want to include underscores... I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Underscores are not considered [alphanumeric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alphanumeric) (they are considered *word* characters, which is what `\w` represents - `\w` is *not* alphanumeric).

Comment: I do not want to include underscores @AlexBaldwin thanks for the help man

Comment: ok, well `[^_\W]` is pretty good then. Short, and it is what you want, since underscores are removed. Of course, you want it to be `^[^_\W]*` so it ensures everything is alphanumeric.